# encountered an error and could not solve it : count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I encountered the error when I try to sign in my application mede by laravel 8.41.0 and PHP 8.0.3.

#### error

```
TypeError
count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given
```

#### location

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:235
```

#### file

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait GuardsAttributes
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]|bool
     */
    protected $guarded = ['*'];

    /**
     * Indicates if all mass assignment is enabled.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $unguarded = false;

    /**
     * The actual columns that exist on the database and can be guarded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $guardableColumns = [];

    /**
     * Get the fillable attributes for the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFillable()
    {
        return $this->fillable;
    }

    /**
     * Set the fillable attributes for the model.
     *
     * @param  array  $fillable
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fillable(array $fillable)
    {
        $this->fillable = $fillable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Merge new fillable attributes with existing fillable attributes on the model.
     *
     * @param  array  $fillable
     * @return $this
     */
    public function mergeFillable(array $fillable)
    {
        $this->fillable = array_merge($this->fillable, $fillable);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the guarded attributes for the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getGuarded()
    {
        return $this->guarded === false
                    ? []
                    : $this->guarded;
    }

    /**
     * Set the guarded attributes for the model.
     *
     * @param  array  $guarded
     * @return $this
     */
    public function guard(array $guarded)
    {
        $this->guarded = $guarded;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Merge new guarded attributes with existing guarded attributes on the model.
     *
     * @param  array  $guarded
     * @return $this
     */
    public function mergeGuarded(array $guarded)
    {
        $this->guarded = array_merge($this->guarded, $guarded);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Disable all mass assignable restrictions.
     *
     * @param  bool  $state
     * @return void
     */
    public static function unguard($state = true)
    {
        static::$unguarded = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Enable the mass assignment restrictions.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function reguard()
    {
        static::$unguarded = false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the current state is "unguarded".
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isUnguarded()
    {
        return static::$unguarded;
    }

    /**
     * Run the given callable while being unguarded.
     *
     * @param  callable  $callback
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function unguarded(callable $callback)
    {
        if (static::$unguarded) {
            return $callback();
        }

        static::unguard();

        try {
            return $callback();
        } finally {
            static::reguard();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given attribute may be mass assigned.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isFillable($key)
    {
        if (static::$unguarded) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the key is in the "fillable" array, we can of course assume that it's
        // a fillable attribute. Otherwise, we will check the guarded array when
        // we need to determine if the attribute is black-listed on the model.
        if (in_array($key, $this->getFillable())) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the attribute is explicitly listed in the "guarded" array then we can
        // return false immediately. This means this attribute is definitely not
        // fillable and there is no point in going any further in this method.
        if ($this->isGuarded($key)) {
            return false;
        }

        return empty($this->getFillable()) &&
            strpos($key, '.') === false &&
            ! Str::startsWith($key, '_');
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given key is guarded.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isGuarded($key)
    {
        if (empty($this->getGuarded())) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->getGuarded() == ['*'] ||
               ! empty(preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($key).'$/i', $this->getGuarded())) ||
               ! $this->isGuardableColumn($key);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given column is a valid, guardable column.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isGuardableColumn($key)
    {
        if (! isset(static::$guardableColumns[get_class($this)])) {
            static::$guardableColumns[get_class($this)] = $this->getConnection()
                        ->getSchemaBuilder()
                        ->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
        }

        return in_array($key, static::$guardableColumns[get_class($this)]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the model is totally guarded.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function totallyGuarded()
    {
        return count($this->getFillable()) === 0 && $this->getGuarded() == ['*'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the fillable attributes of a given array.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillableFromArray(array $attributes)
    {
        if (count($this->getFillable()) > 0 && ! static::$unguarded) {
            return array_intersect_key($attributes, array_flip($this->getFillable()));
        }

        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

Some questioners ask same question and I saw that in latest version of PHP count issue the error. But i could not understood how to resolve the problem, so please tell me where and how to fix in my file.

#### thanks for responses!!

$fillable is declared with squared brackets, all files is added in above.
How can I modify it?

#### model.php (only fillable related)

```
    public function fill(array $attributes)
    {
        $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();

        foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value) {
            // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
            // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
            // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
            if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
                $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
            } elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
                throw new MassAssignmentException(sprintf(
                    'Add [%s] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                    $key, get_class($this)
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

#### app\model user.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = 'name';
}
```

Comment: add check like is_array($this->getFillable()) && count($this->getFillable())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triple check that `$this->getFillable()` (line 235) is giving you an array.

I bet it is not, you probably just forgot the square brackets in your model when you declared the `$fillable` attributes.

In your model, it should looks like this:

```php
protected $fillable = [
        'attribute_a',
        'attribute_b',
        'attribute_c',
        //...
    ];
```

---

*TypeError* is a new type of errors introduced in PHP 8.0. As the name suggests, it is thrown when the type you give to a function is not the type PHP expects.

In your case, `count()` expects an array but since the `$fillable` properties of your model is very likely a simple string, a TypeError is thrown.

Comparison between PHP versions:

**< 8.0**

```php
count('helloworld'); // 1
```

**>= 8.0**

```php
count('helloworld'); // TypeError
```

Comment: This error (and many other) does not related to the framework files. You should look in YOUR OWN code. Can you add all error lines?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I think you made a mistake, your comment was probably intended for the question, not my answer, but your are right, these files should not be touched. I think the author is pointing the line 235 of `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:235` because that's the last line in his error stack trace, however I highly suspect his problem to be the `$fillable` attributes of the related model (which is unfortunately not in his question).

Comment: @toyi and RouhollahMazarei Thank you for your answers. All contents of my document is added my question line. Could you advice to my file?

Comment: Can you add the model and the action that leads to this error please?

Comment: One thing to understand is that GuardsAttributes is a vendor file, you should never touch this file (or only for testing purposes, but it should not be modified). Therefore, copy / pasting here is not useful because we know the problem is not here (and we can also check on our side, we have the same file). I know it's the last file in your error strack trace, but it is almost 100% sure the problem is not here. That's why we need to know what you are trying to achieve and how you are doing it :)

Comment: @toyi understood that the vendor file never be touched. The error occurs when I try to sign up my application with username, email address and password(and also password confirmation). I added model.php in my question line!

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not the file I need :p You added Model.php, this is also a vendor file. I need the actual model (User, Product, Order....) which is in your app\Models directory (if you use Laravel 8). For instance, you are talking about an username, an email address... so I guess you are trying to do something with the User. Can you update your question with the content of this model please ? Thank you

Comment: @toni Sorry I mistook your request. I updated app\model user.php file in my question.

Comment: As your instruction I modified the file with "protected $fillable = ['name'];", and another error is shown, but in this situation, error in title has already solved?
The new error is "BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\user::getAuthIdentifier()".

Comment: Yes the initial error of your question is indeed solved :) I hope you understood what was wrong. I see you are new to stackoverflow, don't forget to to validate the answer so other people with the same error can quickly find the solution. For the next error, I encourage you to open another question describing what you are doing, what is the exact error... Have a good day :)

Comment: @toyi Thank you for this time to cooperate to solve my question! I remember your advice, good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can swap count() with isset()

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem on a client's Drupal website. Its' forum module would not load and was giving out this error.

The issue was rooted in a .svg file posted by one of the users. We went back through the comments in the admin panel and came across a comment made a few hours earlier followed by a .svg file. Drupal could not load the file and had replaced it with
[image: this red x]
that is how we realized this is the issue. We think it only caused the issue when the post was heading to page 2 of the forum.

Removing the SVG solved the problem. We are not planning to find and fix the piece which has caused this, instead, we plan to prevent the addition of SVG files in the forum. That is how we solved the problem. Hope it helps someone.